# In HTML Email Template lookup field showing Name field of the related lookup object, how can I get Id instead?

Tags: email-template, email-alert

I have two objects **Parent** and **Child**, I have created email alert on child with HTML email template, I have to send the link of site page in that mail template with URL parameter as Id of Parent, but when I used merge field as `{!Child__c.Parent__c}` it is populating value from Name field on Parent Record. How can I get Id instead?

Comment: Have you tries `{!Child__c.Parent__r.Id}`

Comment: Yes I tried but its not supported in email templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `{!Child__c.ParentId__c}` to get the ID of the field.